# Angular how i can initialize and populate array with async and promise

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, asynchronous, promise

Below  my component and my service

### report.component.html

```
<div *ngFor="let report of reports">
        <p>{{report.name}}</p>
        <p>{{report.value}}</p>
        <p>{{report.color}}</p>
</div>
```

### report.component.ts

```
export class ReportComponent implements OnInit{

reports = this.reportService.getLists('2020-03-20', '2020-03-26');

constructor(private reportService: ReportService) {}

ngOnInit(){}
}
```

### report.service.ts

```
export class ReportService {


async getLists(startDate: string, endDate: string) {
    this.getReport('2020-03-20', '2020-03-26').then(response => {
      let lists = [
    {
        name: 'Opens',
        value: response .opens, //2
        color: 'green',
      },
        {
        name: 'Closes',
        value: response .opens, //1
        color: 'red',
      }];
      return lists;
    });
  }

 async getReport(startDate: string, endDate: string) {
    return await this.http
      .get<Report>(
       `https://localhost:44354/report?startDate=${startDate}&endDate=${endDate}`,
        this.httpOptions
      )
      .toPromise();
  }
 }
```

It's possible to initialize and populate the array list ?

I want use ngFor loop in my template,
I don't know if i init the array in component or service. What's the best solution ?

**Update**

```
export class ReportComponent implements OnInit {
  reports: any;

  constructor(private reportService: ReportService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    // you still need to subscribe to obtain the result
    this.reportService.getLists('2020-03-20', '2020-03-26').subscribe(  
      response => { 
           this.reports = response;  
           console.log(this.reports);  
    });
  }
}
```

I test your answer but, it's doesn't work, 
I just try if init my array with value, and i have the result on my template

so I think, the init array is not good..

I want just init the propery value from array List with the report object 
exemple  this.list[0].value = report.opens
I don't know if its clear....

**Output**

```
(2) […]
    0: {…}
        name:"Opens"
        value: 2
        color:"green"
        <prototype>: Object { … }
    1: {…}
        name:"Closes"
        value: 1
        color: "red"
        <prototype>: Object { … }
    ​length: 2
    ​<prototype>: Array []
```

Above the console.log(this.report) in the component.

**Update 2**

```
<ng-container *ngIf="reports">
  <p>test</p>
  <div *ngFor="let report of reports">
    <p>{{report.name}}</p>
    <p>{{report.value}}</p>
    <p>{{report.color}}</p>
  </div>
</ng-container>
```

the template not shwo the paragraphe "test"...... the variable stats is null i think

**Update 3**

report.component.html

```
<ng-container *ngIf="reports">
  <p>test</p>
  <div *ngFor="let report of reports">
    <p>{{report.name}}</p>
    <p>{{report.value}}</p>
    <p>{{report.color}}</p>
  </div>
</ng-container>
```

report.component.ts

```
export class SmtpComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit, OnDestroy {
reports:any[] = [];
}
```

I change `reports: any;` to `reports:any[] = [];`

and i can display the paragraphe "test", 
its possible init array with the property 'value, name and color' ?

**Update 4**

```
    this.reportService.getReport('2020-03-20', '2020-03-26').subscribe(
      response => { this.lists= response;   this._cdr.detectChanges()},
      error => { console.log("Error")}
    );
```

Comment: Please be more specific. Where do you want to initialize and populate array? And in what purpose? The problem is to use reports as array in ngFor directive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to make a synchronous call that in turn makes an asynchronous request. That will not work. When you are making an asynchronous call somewhere in the call chain, you need to follow it's rules. It will not return a synchronous data however you try.

You could on the other hand map the response of the asynchronous call to the array of your format. But to retrieve this array you still need to adhere to the rules of asynchronous request.

Try the following

Service

```js
export class ReportService {
  public getReport(startDate: string, endDate: string): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(`https://localhost:44354/report?startDate=${startDate}&endDate=${endDate}`, this.httpOptions)
      .pipe(map(response => {
        return 
        [
          { name: 'Opens', value: response.opens, color: 'green' },
          { name: 'Opens', value: response.opens, color: 'green' }
        ]
      }));
  }
}
```

Controller

```js
import { Component, OnInit, ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';

export class ReportComponent implements OnInit {
  reports: any

  constructor(private reportService: ReportService, private _cdr: ChangeDetectorRef) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    // you still need to subscribe to obtain the result
    this.reportService.getLists('2020-03-20', '2020-03-26').subscribe(  
      response => { this.reports = response },
      error => { // handle error }
    );
    this._cdr.detectChanges();
  }
}
```

**Update**

You could also check before you render the data.

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="reports">
  <div *ngFor="let report of reports">
    <p>{{report.name}}</p>
    <p>{{report.value}}</p>
    <p>{{report.color}}</p>
  </div>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: @Micheal D, thank for you help, my component get the value from the service, but why the template not display the value ?

Comment: @Micheal D, I use your code, and I update the question.

Comment: @Heptagram: Could you please post the output of console.log() to the question?

Comment: @Heptagram: Please remove initializing `reports` in the component, run the code and post the console log. Do `reports: any`.

Comment: @Micheal D, the output is whit reports:any.

Comment: @Heptagram: Then there is no reason for it not render in the template. Could you please post the entire report.component.html?

Comment: @Micheal D; Update 2 - just the min for check

Comment: The last option I have is to trigger change detection manually. Please see my changes to the controller code and try if it works for you. If not, I am out of options.

Comment: @Micheal D, Yes it's working, thank you for your help :). I just edit the controller in update4. I make a resume for help may be others people;

Answer (score 0):

if i use this, i can see in log the object return, but Why the template not work for loop on the array list ?

```
export class ReportComponent implements OnInit {
  reports: any

  constructor(private reportService: ReportService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    // you still need to subscribe to obtain the result
    this.reportService.getLists('2020-03-20', '2020-03-26').subscribe(  
      response => { 
           this.reports = response;  
           console.log(this.reports);  
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: You should post any updates to the question. Not as answer. I've also updated my answer. Please check if it works

Comment: sorry, I start on StackOverFlow